# Celery не может подключится к базе Postgres Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, celery

столкнулся с проблемой, когда добавлял celery в проект и все в общем шло нормально celery и celery beat работает пока речь не идет о таске с каким либо запросом в бд, при том что сам django с postgres работает отлично имея одни и те же енвы, ошибка и код ниже,решение в интернете не нашел

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
    container_name: app
    image: app
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn app.wsgi:application -c gunicorn.conf.py"
    env_file:
        - .env
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

      - redis
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - main

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.18.0-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app/logs:/app/logs
      - ./app/staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - ./app/mediafiles:/app/media
      - ./configs/nginx/${NGINX_FOLDER}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./configs/nginx/certificates:/etc/nginx/conf.d/certificates
      - ./frontend/build:/var/www/html/frontend
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./configs/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - main

 
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    container_name: "redis"


  celery:
    build:
      context: ./app
    command: celery -A app.celery worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  celery-beat:

    build:
      context: ./app
    command: celery -A app.celery beat -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

volumes:
  postgresql_data:

networks:
  main:
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery, shared_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
app = Celery('app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'hello': {
        'task': 'app.celery.hello',
        'schedule': crontab()  # выполнять каждую минуту
    },
    'check_meetings': {
        'task': 'meetings.tasks.check_meetings',
        'schedule': crontab()  # выполнять каждую минуту
    }
}

app.autodiscover_tasks()


@shared_task
def hello():
    print('Hello, world')


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

.env

```
POSTGRES_DB=database
POSTGRES_USER=super_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=super_password
POSTGRES_HOST=db
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json'
```

Сама ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
celery_1       |    Is the server running locally and accepting
celery_1       |    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: ошибку лучше добавлять текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если приложение действительно работает, то проблема, очевидно в различии конфигураций приложения и `celery`. Из того, что сразу бросается в глаза:

1. контейнер `celery` не добавлен в сеть `main`, по-этому `celery` не сможет присоединиться, даже если будет знать адрес БД.
2. конфигурация из `.env` не передается контейнеру `celery` (и в частности параметры типа `POSTGRES_HOST` не устанавливаются при запуске `celery`), по-этому используются параметры по-умолчанию, и `celery` ищет БД на локальном хосте т.е. в том же контейнере.

Нужно добавить конфигурацию, как это сделано для приложения:

```
    celery:
     ....
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - main
```

Comment: Это логично,но проблему не решило(

Comment: Добавил еще про `.env` файл